# Python: input function not accessible on website?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a script and it works on Anaconda. However, on the website (hosted by namecheap), the input function doesn't seem to work, what is wrong?

Website address: http://xterraminer.com.au/cgi-bin/nctests.py

Have already set up namecheap python to Django, not sure if this helped.

```
> user_input=float(input("What is your income?")) tax=float()
> take_home=float() if user_input<=18200:
>     print("You pay $0 tax") elif user_input>18200 and user_input<=37000:
>     tax=(user_input-18200)*0.19
>     print("Your tax is $",tax) elif user_input>37000 and user_input<=90000:
>     tax=(user_input-37000)*0.325+3572
>     print("Your tax is $",tax) elif user_input>90000 and user_input<=180000:
>     tax=(user_input-18200)*0.37+20797
>     print("Your tax is $",tax) elif user_input>180000:
>     tax=(user_input-18200)*0.45+54097
>     print("Your tax is $",tax) take_home=user_input-tax print("Your take home pay is $", take_home)
```

Would expect the website asking for an input

Comment: Are you folowing some sort of tutorial?

Comment: You want to serve an html page with a form that captures the user input, and have request handler that accepts the submitted form, generates the output and sends it back to the browser.  If you have installed Django I strongly recommend going through the excellent [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: @PedroRodrigues not following a tutorial, just wanting to make a calculator

Comment: @snakecharmerb ok thanks i'll check it out